# How do you consolidate "date. Time1 and Time2"?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How do you consolidate "date. Time1 and Time2"

For example:

```
    A                 B         C 
1  Date            Time1      Time2
2  09/04/2016      05:03:15   AM
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is very difficult to understand what you are describing in your post. Are you trying to combine the data from the three cells or combine the data in another cell? Please take a few minutes to explain what the problem is, what you have done to try to resolve it and where you are stuck. Then ask a specific question. If you need help, read [ask] in the [help].

Comment: 1) What is actually stored in each cell (date/time vs. text)?  2) Are you trying to turn it into a single value that is the combined date/time and format it to display all of the elements, or create a text string of the values (Tyson's answer)?

Answer (score 1):

See if

=concatenate(A2," ",B2," ",C2)

Is what you're looking for, if not please be more specific with what you need.